# Combining Google Analytics (gtag.js) and Google Tag Manager (gtm.js)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Google Analytics new migration to "Global site tag" using Google Tag manager confuses me a lot. It is Tag Manager, but it's not!?

The regular **Google Tag Manager** integration looks like this:

```
<!-- Google Tag Manager -->
<script>
  (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
  new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
  j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
  'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
  })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-XXXXXXX');
</script>
```

And the **Google Analytics Global site tag** integration like this:

```
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXXXXXX-X"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());
  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX-X');
</script>
```

They load **different resources**. But **both initiate the dataLayer** push method. The way the object is created differs (supposing the two ways are interchangeable). Are we supposed to use both integrations side by side although the dataLayer object in one implementation conflicts the other?

On a side note. Both resources are bundled with **jQuery 1.9.1**. While it can't be optimal to load and instantiate jQuery twice, (or thrice if we have our own jQuery on top of this). Are there any workarounds or recommendations?

Comment: GTM/Gtag are not bundled with jQuery. The GTM code has a built-in selector engine that resembles jQuery enough so that Google agreed  to include jQuery's copyright notices, but it's not (even close to) a full jQuery library. This information comes from a Google Developer expert (Simo Ahava) so I trust that it's accurate.

Comment: It says jQuery 1.9.1 by jQuery Foundation in the source code. Have a quick look https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js

Comment: I had a look a long time ago, which is why is I asked when I had the chance, The answer relayed in my comment is the one I got.

Comment: It uses some code copied from jQuery 1.9.1, but doesn't include the whole thing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From the [gtag.js Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/#google_tag_manager_or_gtagjs):

> If you are already using Tag Manager, you should continue to do so. If you don't need a tag management system, it is fine to use the gtag.js tracking codes provided by each product.
>
> Tag Manager and gtag.js are built on the same infrastructure, and should work properly if deployed on the same page.

The **Global Site Tag** (`gtag.js`) is a new way of *using* `analytics.js` together with other Google products like AdWords or DoubleClick.
In fact, `gtag.js` loads up the same old `analytics.js` next to other libraries depending on what services you configure. In case you configure it with an AdWords account with `gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXX-X');`, the script will automatically load up `conversions.js` too. Moreover, `gtag.js` also does some basic initialization of the services, e.g. triggers a pageview hit for Analytics or a remarketing hit for AdWords.

That being said, it is a bit like a tag manager indeed. However, it works only with Google products. So it is more of a simplification of configuration of the various Google tags by wrapping all of them into a single one.

It is important to note that if you are setting up a new Analytics account, you get the tracking code in the Global Site Tag format! You have no choice.

On the other hand, **Google Tag Manager**, like most tag management systems, enables you to manage tags beyond the Google suite of products. It comes with a user interface, version control, access management and all the other fancy things. Like `analytics.js` was, `gtag.js` is just another JavaScript library with which Tag Manager can communicate.

Comment: I assume it cannot be used simultaneously for two services as dataLayer.push(['config', 'AW-XXXXXXXX-X']) followed by dataLayer.push(['config', 'UX-XXXXXXXX-X']); dataLayer.push(['event', {obj}]) would reset the service to the last config? Meaning Adwords would not recceive any events?

Comment: One of the main purposes of `gtag.js` is definitely to configure it with multiple google products, like it is mentioned here: https://developers.google.com/gtagjs/devguide/add. The `Array.push()` method does not clears the array, but appends the new value to the end of the array, so previously pushed configs will not be overwritten.

Comment: Thank you. I assumed as the event does not specify which service it is intented for that only the last configured service would pick it up. Now I understand Google might be having some internal mapping and referencing that sorts this problem out. I appreciate your time and effort in providing an answer to this topic. :)